# Glassfish connecting to Server, but wrong port number

Tags: glassfish, port, admin

I'm trying to connect to the glassfish server. It's telling that it has connected successfully, but the port number is -1, and I am unable to see the log file. How do I connect to the default 4848, and 8080 port numbers specified in the asenv batch file?

```
Use "exit" to exit and "help" for online help.
asadmin> start-domain domain1
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:C:\iuclid6\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
        at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:459)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:326)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(GFLauncherLogger.java:99)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:192)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartDomainCommand.java:228)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartDomainCommand.java:124)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.MultimodeCommand.executeCommands(MultimodeCommand.java:250)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.MultimodeCommand.executeCommand(MultimodeCommand.java:151)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:322)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:366)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:300)
        at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:56)
Waiting for domain1 to start
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: C:\iuclid6\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log File: C:\iuclid6\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin Port: -1
Command start-domain executed successfully.
asadmin>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your port numbers but with file access rights.

Maybe you started Glassfish before with an Admin user and now you are using a normal user. I'm talking about Windows users (looks like you are on Windows).

To solve you problem:

- make sure no Glassfish instance is running (have a look for Java processes in your task manager)
- delete the file `C:\iuclid6\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log.lck`
- go to the `asadmin` console and do `start-domain domain1`
- this should start the server, if no error message is shown you can open your browser and go to http://localhost:4848

If it's not working, the server log file should be located here: `C:\iuclid6\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log`